# Output of readlink command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

In my current directory `/home/user/Desktop/projects`, I have a folder (`dev_12`) which has a symbolic link another folder (`now`) in the same directory.

I'm running the following command, to get which folder `dev_12` is pointing to:

```
$ readlink dev_12
/home/user/Desktop/projects/now
```

However, I want to just get `now`. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `readlink` from GNU coreutils gives exactly what the link contains. `readlink -f`, however, resolves the full path to the target. If you have a link that has a directory part, you can't be sure that it points to the current directory, you'd need to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readlink` command would return `now` if that was indeed the content of your link.

If you use `ls -l dev_12`, you will see that the link is to `/home/user/Desktop/projects/now`.

Answer (score 2):

```
basename -- "$( readlink dev_12 )"
```

This calls the `basename` utility with the output of the `readlink` utility for the given symbolic link.  The `basename` utility will return a string which is the filename component of the pathname of the `now` directory, i.e. the final bit after the last `/` in the pathname, or in other words, just the string `now` out of the string `/home/user/Desktop/projects/now`.